# Get part of string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string formatted like this:

`item_questions_attributes_abc123_id`

I'm specifically trying to get the `abc123` bit. That string can be any alphanumeric of any case. No special characters or spaces.

I'm using jQuery, though I'm certainly fine with using straight javascript if that's the best solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's always the 4th part of the string you can use split.

```
var original = 'item_questions_attributes_abc123_id';
var result = original.split('_')[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var myArray = myString.split("_");
alert(myArray[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method of javascript and then use 2nd last index you will have your required data.